# Is there support for transactions in SQLite for android?

Tags: android

Is there support for transactions in SQLite for android ? I need to insert some data in two tables or to inform user if it fails. I need transaction for that. How to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29) is documentation about possible transactions and correct using

Answer (score 2):

SQLiteDatabase has functions beginTransaction, setTransactionSuccessfull and endTransaction. Use them.